# How to set X-Mailgun-Campaign-Id header in Mailgun php API?

Tags: php, api, mailgun

How to set up header "X-Mailgun-Campaign-Id" in Mailgun php API?

I'm using the following code, but I don't know how to pass campaign ID in the header:

```
Mail::send('email.message', $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
    $message->to($data['to_email'], $data['to_name'])
        ->subject($data['subject'])
        ->from($data['from_email'], $data['from_name'])
        ->header('X-Mailgun-Campaign-Id', 'test campaign');
});
```

Comment: This is just asking for coding help, which is [off-topic for SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please describe the desired behaviour or the problem at hand.

Comment: @Demitrian question updated with desired behavior

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution has been found:

```
Mail::send('emails.test3', array(), function ($message) {
    $message->to('barsnur@gmail.com')
        ->subject('Смоторим ответа об открытии')
        ->from('noreply@mg.offer.bz');

    $headers = $message->getHeaders();
    $headers->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Variables', '{"id_message": "666"}');
    $headers->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Tag', 'test-tag');
    $headers->addTextHeader('X-Mailgun-Campaign-Id', 'sDas7d');
});
```

List of available headers are for the link https://documentation.mailgun.com/user_manual.html#sending-via-smtp